# How to create image slideshow in html?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I wanna make image slideshow on my web, here's my code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src = "images/pentagg.jpg"
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "images/promo.jpg"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="images/pentagg.jpg" width="500" height="300" name="slide" /></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function slideit()
            {
                var step=1;
                document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src")
                if(step<2)
                    step++
                else
                    step=1
                setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
            }
            slideit()
    </script>
</body>
```

Why it's not working? I've put image I want in images folder

Comment: You have declared the function slideit(), but you don't call it anywhere.

Comment: `;` at end of each row are missing

Comment: @Matthias `slideit()` is called just after its declaration

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia what I know is script language doesn't need any ; cmiiw :)

Comment: Done, just move var step out from function

Comment: @greenthunder, why haven't you selected an answer? Is your question still unanswered?

Answer (score 13):

1. Set var step=1 as global variable by putting it above the function call
2. put semicolons

It  will look like this

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "images/pentagg.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "images/promo.jpg"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="images/pentagg.jpg" width="500" height="300" name="slide" /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<2)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: So what about binding the slider to a click instead? So that the user could scroll through it and not have to wait on the timer?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing the code from the scratch you can use jquery plug in. Such plug in can provide many configuration option as well.

Here is the one I most liked.

http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider

Comment: You don't have to learn jquery to use this plug in. Just follow the well explained instructions. That much is suffice.