# Advanced html slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860671/how-to-create-image-slideshow-in-html) to have a slidehow of promo images, everything working nice, but i would like to add a few things to it, like image transition (fade in) and little dots on the right bottom corner showing which image i am viewing and have the ability to switch to another image

How can i do this?

I am working on the circle buttons now, and the code looks like this so far

```
<div id="feature-image">

        <img id="promo-image" src="images/pentagg.jpg" width="100%" height="800px" name="slide" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var step=1;
                var imagesTotal= 2;
                var circleDiv;
                function slideit()
                {
                    document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
                    if(step<imagesTotal)
                        step++;
                    else
                        step=1;
                    setTimeout("slideit()",5000);
                }
                slideit();

                function createCircles()
                {
                    for (i=0; i<imagesTotal; i++) {
                        circleDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        circleDiv.className = 'results';
                        circleDiv.style.width = '32px';
                        circleDiv.style.height = '32px';
                        circleDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4444';
                        circleDiv.innerHTML = '<span class="msg">Hello world.</span>';
                        document.getElementsByTagName('feature-image')[0].appendChild(circleDiv);
                        //document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(circleDiv);
                    }
                }
                createCircles();




    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer

You can use a CSS "Hack" of sorts to position the circles at the bottom of your div by making the wrapping div have `position: relative` and the inner elements have `position: absolute`

http://jsfiddle.net/wWunK/