# How to make images change automatically

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am trying to do a featured content slider something like the top banner in this website http://www.homeplus.co.kr

As you can see, the top big banner changes automatically & also will change when user hovers over one of the list at the right.

Right now I am able to do the hovering part, but I am still stuck at the automatic changing content part.

Here's a sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/StormSdq/5tWPy/2/

```
<div class="pi">a</div>
<div class="pi">b</div>
<div class="pi">c</div>
<div class="pi">d</div>
<div class="c1">I DREAM</div>
<div class="c1">OF LLAMAS</div>
<div class="c1">JUMPING AROUND</div>
<div class="c1">EATING BUSHES</div>
```

css:

```
.pi {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:700;
    width:30px;
    height:25px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background:transparent;
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;
}
.c1 {
    border:1px solid blue;
    background:lightskyblue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:430px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    color:red;
    font-size:25px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
```

javascript:

```
div = document.getElementsByClassName('c1');
div[0].style.display = 'block'
B = document.getElementsByClassName('pi');
B[0].onmouseover = function () {
    blip(0);
};
B[1].onmouseover = function () {
    blip(1);
};
B[2].onmouseover = function () {
    blip(2);
};
B[3].onmouseover = function () {
    blip(3);
};

function blip(y) {
    div = document.getElementsByClassName('c1');
    for (x = 0; x < (div.length); x++) {
        div[x].style.display = 'none';
    }
    div[y].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You've tagged this with jQuery but you don't appear to be using it at all in your JSFiddle example. Are you sure you're looking for a jQuery answer?

Comment: Sorry i thought jquery and javascript is the same lol. sorry for the mistake. but is it possible to do it just by using javascript ?

Comment: No worries. :) jQuery is a popular JavaScript library available at http://jquery.com.

Comment: This is how a question should be asked!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a common issue that already has many answers. It's recommended to search before asking. For example, [How to create image slideshow in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860671/how-to-create-image-slideshow-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cur = 0; // current index
setInterval(autoAnim, 2000); // auto change every 2s

function autoAnim(){
    if(cur > 3) cur = 0;
    blip(cur);
    cur++;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/5tWPy/3/)

Comment: WOW ! thank you ! This works like magic ! haha thank youu very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `setTimeout` to call something after XX miliseconds.

```
var number=0;
setTimeout(automatic,5000);  // every 5 seconds

function automatic(){
  blip(number);
  number++;
  if (number > 4)
    number=0;
  alert("Hello");
  setTimeout(automatic,5000);
}
```

You will probably want to make the function sleep when mouse is hover and some others condtions

Comment: Do you mean `setInterval`? setTimeout does it only once, setInterval continues to execute each N milliseconds..

Comment: No, I mean `setTimeout` . See the end of the automatic function which run an other setTimeout. But setInterval might be a better choice (as answered by hicurin)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to say that your answer is incorrect, it would work of course, I just wanted to point out that avoiding unnecessary recursion might be a good thing to do.

Comment: hye ! thank you for suggesting your answer yea ! I appreciate it vry much !