# Adding Buttons to slide, HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the found the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860671/how-to-create-image-slideshow-in-html)

how does one go about adapting this code in the form of adding buttons to go forwards and backwards in the slideshow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explaining:

Slide forward:

Make a button with the following onclick event

```
<button onclick="slideit()">forward</button>
```

If you don't want the slide to change every two and a halve seconds, just put this `//` before the line:

```
setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
```

or delete it.

Slide backward:

```
<button onclick="slideback()">back</button>
```

function for sliding backward:

```
var numSlides = ;

function slideback() {
   document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
   if (step > 1) {
      step--;
   }
   else {
      step=numSlides;
   }

}
```

You need to set `numSlides` to the number of slides you have.

### Summary:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="slideback()">back</button>    
<button onclick="slideit()">forward</button>
```

Script:

```
var numSlides = ;
var autoplay= ;

function slideback() {
   document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
   if (step > 1) {
      step--;
   }
   else {
      step = numSlides;
   }

}

function slideit() {
   var step=1;
   document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src")
   if (step < numSlides) {
      step++
   }
   else {
      step = 1
   }
   if (autoplay == true) {
   setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
   }
}
```

Set autoplay to true/false for autoplay,
set numSlides to your number of slides